# returing nodeValues using while loop

Tags: php

I am using xpath to get various elements on a page. If I use a foreach loop like this `foreach ($company as $node) { echo $node->nodeValue. "<br>"; }` it works but I am only able to return values from one variable so that means I have to create two separate foreach loops. I want to be able to use the while loop so I can return both values from variable at the same time. The while loop doesnt return any error or values.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($source);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$company = $xpath->query("//*[@class='name']");
$address = $xpath->query("//*[@class='address']");

$i = 0;

while ($i < count($company)) {
   echo $company->nodeValue. "<br>";
   echo $address->nodeValue. "<br><br>";
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: you might be approaching this with the wrong XPath. Please provide a sample of your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [`NodeLists`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), to retrieve individual nodes by index, use [`->item()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php)

```
while ($i < $company->length ) {
   echo $company->item($i)->nodeValue. "<br>";
   echo $address->item($i)->nodeValue. "<br><br>";
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: yes, but this will only work when the address nodelist has an equal or greater amount of items. Otherwise, you'll get errors.

Comment: @Gordon I assume they always have equal length from the OP's code. Just fixing a simple error here, not providing higher lever advice.

Comment: @Esailija works, but for `count($company)` it only returns 1 but there should be 30 nodes. is there like a itemList or nodeList? so i could use count() on it?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 try `while( $i < $company->length )`